# Execute code when iOS app is totally closed (killed)

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, background, apple-push-notifications

Essentially what I want to achieve is to receive a silent notification that has some data, in order to save that data using NSUserDefaults and also show a local notification. I'm already doing this and it is working when app is in foreground and background (not closed), the problem is that when the app is totally closed (killed) this is not working. I've being researching a lot and it seems like this could be done using silent notifications, that's the reason because I'm using them. But for some reason this is not working for me.

**EDIT:**
My notification payload is:

```
{  
    aps: {  
        content-available: 1  
    },  
    u: { customData: "My custom data" }  
}
```

Comment: What is the silent notification's payload? Per the Apple docs it must have the property "content-available" set to 1 and must not contain a value for alert, badge, or sound.

Comment: @SeanG please check my edit.

Comment: Did you enable remote notifications on your project capabilities menu?

Comment: What evidence do you have that it's not working? Are you killing it in the simulator and then running it w/ "Wait for Launch" checked in the scheme?